# Using R to manipulate dataframe: each row of a column to separate columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a longer dataframe with student name, subjects, question names and their marks. A short version of this dataframe looks like the below:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 
A  1  a   1
A  1  b   0.5
A  1  c   1
A  2  a   2
A  2  b   1.5
A  2  c   3
A  2  d   3
B  1  a   0
B  1  b   1.5
B  1  c   2
B  2  a   2
B  2  b   2.5
B  2  c   4
B  2  d   5
```

Here A, B are students, 1,2 are subjects, a, b,c are question names and the last column is marks obtained by each student, in each subject and in each question.

I would like to consolidate part of dataframe with question name column becoming heading for several columns with corresponding marks like below:

```
Student         Sub:1         Sub:2
Name       a    b     c     a   b  c  d
A          1   0.5    1     2  1.5 3  3
B          0   1.5    2     2  2.5 4  5
```

I can use transpose function (`t(dataframe)`) to switch column to rows but I don't know how to do partly retaining details of students and marks.
Can some one guide how can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at `pivot_wider` in the `dplyr` package for one canned way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`, supplying column names from `c2` and `c3` columns and value from `c4`.

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df,names_from = c(c2, c3),values_from = c4, names_prefix = "Sub")

#  c1    Sub1_a Sub1_b Sub1_c Sub2_a Sub2_b Sub2_c Sub2_d
#  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A          1    0.5      1      2    1.5      3      3
#2 B          0    1.5      2      2    2.5      4      5
```

---

Or with `data.table`, `dcast`

```
data.table::dcast(df, c1~paste0("Sub",c2)+c3, value.var = "c4")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
c2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), c3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
c4 = c(1, 0.5, 1, 2, 1.5, 3, 3, 0, 1.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Thanks for that really quick solution. I get an error: Error: 'pivot_wider' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'

Comment: @shiva I think you need to update your `tidyr` library, the function is from tidyr 1.0.0. do `install.packages('tidyr')` and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for that...I am getting a dataframe full of values like 1 BDSF1146 <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
2 BDSF1324 <NULL> <NULL> <NULL>..am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @shiva Do you have same data as shown in your question? Or do you have some additional columns? Can you use the data which I have shared in my answer and see if it gives the output as shown?

Comment: Yes, with the sample data, your code works exactly as required. When handling my data, I get warning like: 
Values in `marks` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(marks = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(marks = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(marks = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

Comment: @shiva Try `df %>%
  select(c1, c2, c3, c4) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(c2, c3),values_from = c4, names_prefix = "Sub")` if it doesn't work then add `dput(head(df))` and update your post with your actual dataframe.

Comment: With this too i get same output. the following is the structure of my df: structure(list(studentid = c("BDSF1146", "BDSF1146", "BDSF1146", 
"BDSF1146", "BDSF1146", "BDSF1146"), sub = c("ICA 1 ARD written-1a", 
"ICA 1 ARD written-1b", "ICA 1 ARD written-2a", "ICA 1 ARD written-2b", 
"ICA 1 ARD written-2c", "ICA 1 ARD written-2d"), marks = c(1, 
1.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205867/discussion-between-shiva-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: @shiva For your updated data, this does work right? `pivot_wider(df,names_from = sub,values_from = marks)`

Comment: There was a duplicate entry and I fixed and it is working like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is base R solution using `reshape()`

```
df$namecol <- with(df,paste0(c2,c3))
dfout <- reshape(df[-c(2:3)],direction = "wide",idvar = "c1",timevar = "namecol")
names(dfout) <- gsub(".*\\.(.*)","\\1",names(dfout))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  c1 1a  1b 1c 2a  2b 2c 2d
1  A  1 0.5  1  2 1.5  3  3
8  B  0 1.5  2  2 2.5  4  5
```